# Data is not being pasted into data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The code is below. I am building a Reddit bot to read comments and email me for certain keywords but I cannot get the comment and submission data into the data frame. I checked the count and it prints correctly. Is it a formatting issue with the count?I tried wraping the df colum title in with the count and that didn't work. If I remove count it will place the top row only, of course.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Post Title': [], 'Post Content': [], 'Comment': [], 'Date & Time': [],
                  'Comment Author': [], 'Post URL': [], 'Sub URL': [], 'Upvotes': []
                   })


print(df)

comment_ids = ['ir0boj1']

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("woodstoving")

count = 0

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=50):
    for comment in submission.comments.list():
        if hasattr(comment, "body"):
            comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
            comment_split = comment_lower.split()
            if 'creosote' in comment_lower:
                if comment.id in comment_ids:
                    continue
                else:
                    comment_ids.append(comment.id)
                    print("Post Title:", submission.title)
                    df['Post Content'][count] = [submission.selftext]
                    df['Comment Author'][count] = [comment.author]
                    df['Comment'][count] = [comment.body]
                    df['Post URL'][count] = [submission.url]
                    df['Sub URL'][count] = [submission.permalink]
                    df['Upvotes'][count] = [comment.score]
                    df['Post Title'][count] = [submission.title]
                    df['Date & Time'][count] = 
                        [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(comment.created_utc)).
                       strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]
                    count += 1
```

EDIT: Figured it out

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Post Title': [], 'Post Content': [], 'Comment': [], 'Date & Time': [],
                  'Comment Author': [], 'Post URL': [], 'Sub URL': [], 'Comment Upvotes': []
                   }, dtype=pd.StringDtype())

print(df)

comment_ids = []

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("woodstoving")


count = 0

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=5):
    for comment in submission.comments.list():
        if hasattr(comment, "body"):
            comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
            comment_split = comment_lower.split()
            if 'creosote' in comment_lower:
                if comment.id in comment_ids:
                    continue
                else:
                    comment_ids.append(comment.id)
                    
                    df = df.append({'Post Title': submission.title,
                                    'Post URL': submission.url,
                                    'Post Content': submission.selftext,
                                    'Comment Author': submission.author,
                                    'Comment': comment.body,
                                    'Sub URL': submission.permalink,
                                    'Comment Upvotes': comment.score,
                                    'Date & Time': [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(comment.created_utc)).strftime
                                                    ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]
                                    }, ignore_index=True)
                    count += 1
```

Comment: Is it printing the post title correctly when using the code above ?

Comment: yes it is, when I print instead of trying to add to the Dataframe everything works

Comment: maybe look at appending to the dataframe rather than the way you are trying to do it.
Create a dictionary of the new values. Eg.   new_row = {"Post Title": submission.title, "Post Content"......}.  And then append the dictionary to the dataframe.

Comment: figured it out, needed to assign for text data to the dataframe.